# shadow shown while using mindmup-editabletable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a editable table using "mindmup-editabletable.js" my problem is condent typing first time is OK. next time when i click the same row for editing first condent shadow is shown only in chrome in other bowers is working good .

[image]

```
$('#table').editableTableWidget({
    cloneProperties: ['background', 'border', ]
});
```

Comment: can you put code what you have done?

Comment: @HareshVidja i use only  this  code for  editable table

Answer (score 1):

Do not clone background properties form table cell to the overlaying `input`, or set the background cell `background-color` to some solid color.

```
$('#table').editableTableWidget({
    cloneProperties: ['border']
});
```

or

```
#table td {
    background: none #fff;
}
```

Comment: but i need background color on editing time. if i remove the background no color is shown on editing time

Comment: than use a solid color as above, do not use alpha channel, no transparency in color.

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: Your edit input field clone/copies the color from your table cell. Obviously it is transparent, so you see the table below it. Make the table cell background color solid, than the overlay input will also get same color, no transparency. The input is placed over the table, to cover the cell, it **does not** temporary replace the content inside the table, ok? Also check your `input:focus` styles in CSS, it **must not** have transparent background color.